# Hindi IME is not ready yet

Tags: powershell, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

We have a requirement where we want to install Hindi Keyboard with Phonetic on user remotely using a schedule task with powershell. The schedule task is run in user mode since running in system mode have no effect. User doesn't have admin right in the system.

We used below code to push the changes to machine but when executed, the keyboard is getting installed but on selection of Phonetic type, user always get "Hindi IME is not ready yet". Out of 10 user we check, for 4 the keyboard got installed but for 6, this error is coming. Any pointer what we could be doing wrong

```
languageCode = "hi-IN"; keyboardCode = "0439:{81EA0A17-AA39-455B-BA20-EA79A8F98966}{26FA8EBD-97DB-4F65-BF35-5E219EBD0079}"

$newLanguageList = New-WinUserLanguageList -Language $languageCode
$newLanguageList[0].InputMethodTips.Clear()
$newLanguageList[0].InputMethodTips.Add($keyboardCode)
$finalLanguageList = $currentLanguageList + $newLanguageList
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $finalLanguageList -Force
```

Comment: Can you successfully install the Hindi IME without using the scheduler?

Comment: We have to someone run the script on those machine remotely

Comment: The script works when run locally, but does not work when run from the scheduer 6 out of 10 time. Is that correct? Does it ever fail when run locally? Is there any more information in the error message?